# Reduce the cyclometic complexity for multiple if else statements

Tags: ios, swift, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a function which accepts a `Textfield` as parameter and based on the tag, the number changes; Here is the code sample

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if(textField.tag == 0){
        measureMentObject?.bloodPressureSystolic = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 1){
        measureMentObject?.bloodPressureDiastolic = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 2){
        measureMentObject?.heartRate = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 3){
        measureMentObject?.bodyTemperature = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 4){
        measureMentObject?.respitoryRate = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 5){
        measureMentObject?.o2Saturation = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 6){
        measureMentObject?.painScale = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 7){
        measureMentObject?.weight = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 8){
        measureMentObject?.po = myNumber
    }else  if(textField.tag == 13){
        measureMentObject?.gastricTube = myNumber
    }
}
```

How do I reduce the cyclometic complexity in this case?

Comment: you can use a switch

Comment: Create enum with Tag and use switch . to identify tag :)

Comment: Check my answer I have added example for you

Comment: @ReinierMelian A switch won't reduce cyclomatic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to get rid of the `if / else if` block, one approach would be:

- subclass UITextField
- give it a `measureMentObjectKey: String` property

Then:

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let tf = textField as? MyTextField {
        let tfKey = tf.measureMentObjectKey
        measureMentObject.setValue(myNumber, forKey: tfKey)
    }
}
```

(with additional error-checking, of course).

Comment: I would recommend to subclass `UITextField` but do it in a generic way. Instead of giving it a `measurementObject`, I would give it a closure `onValueChanged`. Then you can just setup your text fields with the correct closures. I am using that in all my projects, the `UITextField` API is old and closures can really improve the usage of it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make an `Array` with some setter closures:

```
class Measurement {
  var bloodPressureSystolic : Float = 0.0
  var bloodPressureDiastolic: Float = 0.0
  var heartRate             : Float = 0.0
  // ...

  // Array of property setters
  lazy var setters:[(Float) -> ()] = [
    { [unowned self] in self.bloodPressureSystolic  = $0 },
    { [unowned self] in self.bloodPressureDiastolic = $0 },
    { [unowned self] in self.heartRate              = $0 }
  ]
}
```

Example use:

```
var bar = Measurement()

print(bar.bloodPressureSystolic)
// "0.0"

bar.setters[0](5.0)

print(bar.bloodPressureSystolic)
// "5.0"
```

Note that this just moves the complexity of a `switch..case` or `if..else` statement to the selection of an `Array` member. It may or may not be more complex under the hood, although if the `Array` is implemented in a certain way it could use a computed offset to find the member.

I would probably add an `enum` for convenience and documentation purposes:

```
  // Convenience enum for property setter array
  enum PropertyValues: Int {
    case bloodPressureSystolic
    case bloodPressureDiastolic
    case heartRate
    // ...
  }
```

You could use it like:

```
bar.setters[Measurement.PropertyValues.bloodPressureSystolic.rawValue](5.0)
```

Another way to do it is to inherit from `NSObject` and use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/):

```
class Measurement:NSObject {
  var bloodPressureSystolic: Float = 0.0
}

bar.setValue(10.0, forKey: "bloodPressureSystolic")
// Example only, avoid forced unwrapped Optionals!!!
print(bar.value(forKey: "bloodPressureSystolic") as! Float)
```

You can then use the same `Array` trick but with `String` values to convert indexes to key strings.

Comment: Nice solution! You can also change the setter to accept the enum directly.

Comment: Sure, I kept the `enum` out of it at first so the OP could use it directly in their code. It would be easy to add a conversion from raw value to `enum`, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You should create enum to create more readable

```
  enum SelectedTagTextField {
    case bloodPressureSystolic = 0
    case bloodPressureDiastolic = 1
    ...
  }
```

And use

```
 switch(SelectedTagTextField(rawValue: textField.tag)) {
    case  SelectedTagTextField.bloodPressureSystolic : 
  .... And So on 
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: FWIW - Your pseudo code should probably be `switch SelectedTagTextField(rawValue: textField.tag) {` to be more explicit

Comment: @AgRizzo Thank you very much for your suggestion. Let me update and check if it is proper now

Comment: I don't thinks so switch statement reduce cyclic complexity in this case, yes it is good for readability not for CC

Answer (score 0):

Simply, don't use one handler. Use multiple:

```
@IBAction
func systolicBloodPressureTextFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    measureMentObject?.bloodPressureSystolic = myNumber
}

@IBAction
func diastolicBloodPressureTextFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    measureMentObject?.bloodPressureDiastolic = myNumber
}
```

and connect them to the `.editingChanged` action.

That will also allow you to avoid those evil tags.